# Apply class to lists with greater than 3 items

Tags: jquery

Given a number of unordered lists, I need to loop through each one on the page and only apply append a class to the end of lists with length greater than 3. I have the following, but it shouldn't be applying the class to the 3rd list, which has only 3 items:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul class="practice-areas-list">
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul class="practice-areas-list">
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
        <li>link 4</li>
        <li>link 5</li>
        <li>link 6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="toggle" tabindex="1">
      <p class="header" onclick="void(0)">LINK</p>
      <ul class="practice-areas-list">
        <li>link 1</li>
        <li>link 2</li>
        <li>link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('ul').each(function() {
  $('li:gt(2)', this).hide()
});
$('ul.practice-areas-list').each(function(){
if($('ul.practice-areas-list li').length > 3){
  $('ul').append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle();
  });
}
});
```

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/949f8ehb/2/)

Comment: Much easier to apply a class server side of course, just saying

Comment: This is still applying the `<li>+</li>` to the list with only 3 elements in it

Comment: @Matt Because you're doing the same thing here: `$('ul').append ...` which says "To *every single `ul`, append...*". Change that to `$(this).append` as well.

Comment: Something is still off here...https://jsfiddle.net/949f8ehb/5/

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an `each` but essentially ignoring it. By using selectors inside an `each` iteration like `$('ul')` or `$('ul.practice-areas-list li')`, you are selecting *all elements that satisfy the selector on the entire page*.

So, with that in mind:

```
// This selects every li on the page. It evaluates to 15.
if ($('ul.practice-areas-list li').length > 3){

// Append to every ul on the page
$('ul').append( ... );
```

To be honest, I don't really have any idea what you're trying to achieve. You didn't describe what your preferred functionality really is, but with what you've given, this is the best I can manage:

```
$('ul.practice-areas-list').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('li').length > 3){
        $(this).append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function() {
            $(this).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed .length to jQuery's [`$.size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) and the `$('ul').append(...)` to `$(this).append(...)` in order to apply the append to the selected `<ul>` tag in particular.

```
$('ul.practice-areas-list').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('li').size() > 3) {
        $(this).append('<li>+</li>').find('li:last').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle();
        });
    }
});
```